# C# Complex Linq - Join two table within a subquery

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, exception

I'm currently working on a system which is using a very complex database.

I need to compile info from multiple tables and associations to display a list like this (I have many of them):

```
[List] (Class `List`)
     [Id]
     [EntityId]
     [Name]
     [Description]
     [Users] (From `List<User> List.AssignedUsers` joined to `List<ListMember> List.Members`)
         [Id]
         [EntityId]
         [Username]
         [FullName]
         [Email]
         [ListId]
         [Order] (From `ListOrder` property in `ListMember` object)
         [Status] (From `Status` property in `ListMember` object)
             [Id]
             [NameEn]
             [NameFr]
             [Color]
             [Type]
             [Tag]
             [Options]
```

In this, `List.AssignedUsers` is the list of users who can access the list. `List.Members` is the list of currently active users in list, containing their status. If a `AssignedUser` is not in `Members`, then the `Status` and `Order` property must be null.

Here's how the DB is designed:

[image: DB Diagram]

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
var lists =
    await (from l in db.Lists.Include("Members").Include("AssignedUsers")
           where l.DateDeleted == null
           select new ListModel
           {
               Id = l.Id,
               EntityId = l.EntityId,
               Name = l.Name,
               Description = l.Description,
               Users = (
                   from u in l.AssignedUsers
                   join lms in l.Members on u.Id equals lms.UserId into members
                   from lm in members.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new UserModel
                   {
                       Id = u.Id,
                       EntityId = u.EntityId,
                       Username = u.Username,
                       FullName = u.FullName,
                       Email = u.Email,
                       ListId = l.Id,
                       Order = (lm == null ? lm.ListOrder : -1),
                       Status = (lm != null ? new StatusModel
                       {
                           Id = lm.Status.Id,
                           Type = lm.Status.Type,
                           Color = lm.Status.Color,
                           Tag = lm.Status.Tag,
                           NameEn = lm.Status.NameEn,
                           NameFr = lm.Status.NameFr,
                           Options = lm.Status.AvailableOptions
                       } : null)
                   }
               ).ToList()
           }).ToListAsync();

return lists;
```

The problem is that this query is very slow, and instead of returning a result, my `w3wp.exe` process crash with a nice window telling me that .NET crashed. The error log says nothing except that:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3dad
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16430, time stamp: 0x55c599e1
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0003dcb9
Faulting process id: 0x4998
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1134884f4b8dd
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 52069c20-912c-428a-b4fc-271851dbaba0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Now, I tried few other ways but I'm searching for the most performant one, and if LINQ can't do it, I'll do it in SQL directly!

Comment: If you're looking for the most performant way and are comfortable in plain SQL, dapper dot net may be a viable option.  Some benchmarks: http://www.dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2014/05/01/speed-comparison-dapper-vs-entity-framework/

Comment: @silencedmessage Well, I'm very confortable with SQL but if there's a way to do it with EF, I'd like that way. Also, no need of Dapper, EF can execute plain SQL queries and return results into DTO objects as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slow because you're preventing the library from using a single query because of your nested `ToList` calls.

If instead you'd just build a nice description of your object, joins and all, and called `ToArray` (why list?) at the end, it would be fine, but your way calls the first part of the query at the beginning, then *for each item returned* calls the subquery to fill the results.

As to why it crashes, it's the equally well written condition: `lm == null ? lm.ListOrder : -1` -- and you could easily see it by simply debugging the process.

Comment: The ToList() is because the Model has a strongly-typed `public ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }`. But what's the difference between ToList and ToArray? And thanks for the notice in the equality (end of week, didn't see it!)

Comment: Corrected the equality and used `IEnumerable<UserModel>` instead of `ICollection`, then removed the ToList. Load within a second now, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `ICollection` is the exact opposite of `IQueryable`, which is what EF is based on. As soon as you drop out of the `IQueryable` world you no longer run on the server, but on your own computer.